# issue after writing workbook with Apache-POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've a problem after inserting the data into the sheet of an excel template with the .xlsm extension. The code works. It correctly copies the data in question, but when I try to run a specific macro, which takes the imported data, it does not recognize all rows, only the first two.

However, if I copy and paste any cells in the second column, e.g. if I copy B2 in B2 and execute the macro, it recognizes the total number of inserted rows. Can you help me? I hope I was clear.

Here is my Function Code

```
public String generarExcelSalida(String codCampaña,JDateChooser fechaParametro,String tfOutFolder){
String fileName="Modelo Caida "+codCampaña+".xlsm";
String exitFilePath=tfOutFolder+"\\"+fileName;
FileInputStream fileIn=null;
FileOutputStream fileOut=null;
SimpleDateFormat dParam=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateParam = dParam.format(fechaParametro.getDate()).toString();
ResultSet rs=DBManager.ConsultaCaida(dateParam, codCampaña);
try {
    // Here I'm opening my template file
    fileIn=new FileInputStream(FileManagement.carpetaTemplate+"\\Template_Caidas.xlsm");

    XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(fileIn));
    XSSFSheet sheet9=workbook.getSheet("BASE_DATOS");

    int i=1; // This parameter is used to getRow(i)
    while(rs.next()){
        XSSFRow row = sheet9.getRow(i);

        XSSFCell cell1=row.getCell(0);
        XSSFCell cell2=row.getCell(1);
        XSSFCell cell3=row.getCell(2);
        XSSFCell cell4=row.getCell(3);
        XSSFCell cell5=row.getCell(4);
        XSSFCell cell6=row.getCell(5);
        //Writing de ResultSet values on Sheet "BASE_DATOS"
        cell1.setCellValue(rs.getString("Producto Comercial"));
        cell2.setCellValue(rs.getInt("Nro Certificados"));
        cell3.setCellValue(rs.getString("DefEstado"));
        cell4.setCellValue(rs.getDate("Año-Mes Venta"));
        cell5.setCellValue(rs.getDate("Año-Mes Inicio Vigencia"));
        cell6.setCellValue(rs.getDate("AM Estado"));
        i++;// next Sheet.row

        }

    fileOut=new FileOutputStream(exitFilePath);
    //writing the workbook in a new file, it is like SAVE AS
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    if(fileOut!=null) fileOut.close();
    if(fileIn!=null) fileIn.close();
} catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException | SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//return the path of the new file
return exitFilePath;
}
```

Here is the macro's code

```
Private Sub Base_Datos()
Dim Numero_Registro As Integer
Dim Celda As Range
Dim Columna, Fila As Integer

Sheets("BASE_DATOS").Select

' Busqueda del limite de Filas
Fila = Range("Numero_Registro") + 1

' Busqueda del limite de Columnas
Set Celda = Range("1:1").Find("BAJAS")
Columna = Celda.Column

With Range("a1")
' Copiar Pegar
Range(.Cells(2, Columna), .Cells(2, 100)).Select
Selection.Copy

Range(.Cells(3, Columna), .Cells(Fila, 100)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show the "specific macro" which fails. Since you never create cells nor rows, all rows and cells must exists **before** your `apache poi` code runs. So the showed code cannot result in problems with "not recognizing all rows". The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I 've just add the macro's  code.

Comment: How is the named range "Numero_Registro" defined? The `Fila` wich is getted from this named range is responsible for how far the formulas are copied. Or does the macro fail with an error? If so which error on which `VBA` code line?

Comment: "Numero_Registro" it's a formula ("=CONTARA(BASE_DATOS!B:B)-1") from the template. But if i dont change or write the same value of any cell in B column after inserting data in the template, it doesn't update the value of "Numero_Registro"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your comments the issue is about the needed recalculation because the macro relies on a cell value which uses `COUNTA` to count filled cells.

Two possible solutions:

First: You could use a `FormulaEvaluator` to let evaluate the formulas from `apache poi` before saving the workbook:

```
...
    //writing the workbook in a new file, it is like SAVE AS
    XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    evaluator.evaluateAll();
    workbook.write(fileOut);
...
```

This may fail dependent of the kind of the formulas.

If it fails using `evaluateAll()` you could at least let evaluate the cell with the `COUNTA` formula. This should not fail since `apache poi` supports `COUNTA` function.

Read [Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) for how to do.

Second: You could force `Excel` to do the recalculation while it is opening the file:

```
...
    //writing the workbook in a new file, it is like SAVE AS
    workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
...
```

This may lead to long time process while opening the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've tried both solution, the first one  hangs the app, but the second one works perfectly. Thanks again!!

Comment: Using the evaluator should be preferred. You could try using `evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);` to evaluate only the one cell containing the `COUNTA`.